# How to parse jsonarray square brackets contents

Tags: java, json

I try this on java with an jar net.sf.json-lib 2.4.

```
Map<String,Object>[] retrievedList = null;
String getTypeParam = "[{ 'foo': '[1234] server' }, { 'foo': '[1234]' }]";
JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(getTypeParam);

list = (Map<String, Object>[]) JSONArray.toArray(jsonArray, HashMap.class);

for (int inx = 0; inx < list.length; inx++) {
    System.out.println(list[inx].get("foo").getClass());
    testDAO.insertTestData(list[inx]);
}
```

When inserting the second data as above, the following error occurs.

```
class java.lang.String
class java.util.ArrayList
com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in egovframework/sqlmap/com/test/sqlmap-test.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the insertTestData-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the parameter mapping for the 'foo' property.  
--- Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

After I printed the list, I could see that the exception was caused by a parsing error in square brackets.

```
0: [{\"foo\" : \"[1234] server\"}]
1: [{\"foo\" : [1234]}]
```

How do I get "1" as a string with square brackets, like "0"?

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "but results... it's an array, not a string."? I'd expect the result to be an array containing a single object, with a property called "foo" which has a string value. Please provide a [mcve] which shows what actually happens.

Comment: Did you actually extract the value of `foo`, or did you just use the result of the `fromObject` call directly and expect that Java would automatically dig down to that value for you?

Comment: where is `JSONArray` class?

Answer (score 0):

If `foo` is returning an array, you could try something like `foo[0].tostring`

This shows you the zero index (the first element) in your array, which should be the variable you are looking for. You also have to convert it to a string, because that is an integer.